# Drupal - Make a validate function for cck form

Tags: php, validation, drupal, forms

I have created different node forms for different content types, by using this function in my template:

```
function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'type1_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'type1_form'
    ),
    'type2_form' => array(
        'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
        'template' => 'type2_form'
    ),
  );
}
```

Now I'd like to make a validate function for one of the forms. I tried using this function in template.php:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id == 'type1_form') {
     $form['#validate'][] = 'my_sample_validate_func';
   }
}

function my_sample_validate_func($form, &$form_state) {
   dsm($form_state);
}
```

But apparently the hook_form_alter isn't avaliable to the theme layer. Do I have to make a new module to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hook_form_alter` must go in a modul, not a template.php file. For most of my Drupal projects I end up creating a glue module just to hold stuff like form_alter functions.

This [Lullabot article](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6) shows how to alter forms with hook_form_alter and in the theme layer, but in my opinion it is easier to do it in a separate module.

Comment: Well then, the easiest solution is often the best. I'll make a glue module for it, hopefully I'll get other uses for it too.

Comment: Oh you definitely will.  Having a glue module opens up more customization than you can imagine with Drupal!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But simpler to create type1_form.tpl.php, type2_form.tpl.php, investigate $form via print_r or devel module.
Also you can use preprocessor of these themers.